# "focusout" jQuery event

Tags: 6, javascript

I am using Drupal 6 and, therefore, jQuery 1.2.6.

When a user clicks inside my text, there is a pop-up that comes up with a few more options in it. I would like this pop up to disappear when the focus is moved to anywhere outside.   [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat) comes very close but the `focusout` event isn't available to me in jQuery 1.2.6.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? How did you work around it?
I would rather not use the [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module, as I don't own the site and don't want to be responsible if the update breaks something else.

Comment: Not sure this question really belongs on Drupal Answers as it's not a Drupal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event to the popup div

Taking the example code from the [SO question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat), see the working version at http://jsfiddle.net/Laxman13/Mw8VD/6/

Comment: Interestingly, your example works great in IE but not in FireFox! I think you are on the right track though.

Comment: @Icode4food try the jsfiddle link now. It works on my end for IE, FF and Chrome

Comment: If I embed another div inside that div it will call the parent div's mouseout event when going into the child. Any suggestions how to work around this? I'm obviously not a js guru, I try to stick with backend PHP stuff but every now and then I get stuck with a ui project. :)

Comment: @Icode4food updated the jsfiddle link again. Removing `mouseout` and only using `mouseleave` works with a child element.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the blur() function.

from the jquery docs

> The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as . In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page.
>   Blockquote

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score -2):

Will it work as expected with jQuery 1.3.2, because you can install the [jQuery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. I normally upgrade jQuery on all drupal 6 sites that I work with due to most jquery plugins etc have compatibility with 1.3.x

Comment: OP mentioned not wanting to use jquery_update in question